# Finding expectation and variance

Tags: probability, statistics

I know what are the generic formulas for numbers, but I'm not so sure about the actual formula if you're given probability density functions. Let $X$ have the pdf $f(x)=0.5(x+1)$ with $-1<x<1$. What would be the Expected $Y$ ($EY$) and Variance of $Y$ or $VY$?

I think $EY = \int \limits _{-1} ^1 0.5(x+1) x^2 \ \Bbb d x = \frac 1 3$, right. To calculate variance, we do $E(Y-EY)^2$, right? But then, would the next integral we have to calculate for variance be $\int \limits _{-1} ^1 (x^2-\frac 1 3)^2 0.5(x+1) \ \Bbb d x$?

Comment: Consider TeXifying your question so as to attract more answers.  =)

Comment: okay, done textifying.

Comment: Your really should clean up the question. More TeX, Confusion between random variables called X and Y, which seem to be the same. Apparent error in method of finding the mean. Apparent error in formula for finding the variance. I hope I have given you enough help in my Answer so you can find your way. Errors seem to be more due to haste than fundamental misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must have mean that the density function (PDF) is $f(x) = .5(x + 1)$ for $x \in (-1,1).$

Just as there are 'generic formulas' for means and variances of
data, there are formulas for the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$
of a continuous random variable $X$ with density function $f(x).$

You should check to make sure your function $f(x)$ really is
a density function: (a) verify that $f(x) \ge 0,$ for such $x,$ and (b) that
$$\int_\infty^\infty f(x)\,dx = \int_{-1}^1 .5(x  + 1)\,dx = 1.$$

Then you need to find
$$\mu = E(X) = \int_{-1}^1 x[.5(x + 1)]\,dx.$$ Try sketching the
density curve from -1 to 1. Does your answer $\mu = 1/3$ seem to be the 'balance'
point of the density curve? The answer may be correct, but your
formula looks wrong.

Then for $\sigma^2 = V(X)$ you can find
$$\sigma^2 = \int_{-1}^1 (x - \mu)^2[.5(x + 1)]\,dx.$$

An alternative method is to use the equality $V(X) = E(X^2) - \mu^2.$
So you could find
$$E(X^2) = \int_{-1}^1 x^2[.5(x + 1)]\,dx$$
and subtract $\mu^2.$

Below is a brief R program that simulates a million realizations
of your random variable and finds some approximations you can
use to check your work. (It happens that your random variable
is related to a beta random variable: $X = 2Y - 1,$ where
$Y \sim Beta(2, 1);$ see your text or the Wikipedia article
on 'beta distribution'.)

```
m = 10^6;  x = 2*rbeta(m, 2, 1) - 1
mean(x);  var(x)
## 0.333737   # approx E(X)
## 0.2219013  # approx V(X)
mean(x^2);  mean(x^2)-mean(x)^2
## 0.3332815  # approx E(X^2)
## 0.2219011  # 2nd approx of V(X)
```

The picture shows a histogram of the million simulated values
and your PDF. The dotted red line is at $\mu = 1/3.$

[image]

Comment: Why do you multiply by x when finding the E(X) in the integral and what is the difference between using EY and EX along with Var(Y) and Var(X)?

Comment: Look at definition of E(X), the x factor is part of the formula. I only see random variable X defined, but I see E(Y) and Var(Y). Is Y a different random variable?